# Retrieving the latest entry for each id with Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Given the MSSQL database table "Readings" (primary key is Id and Updated)

| Id | Updated | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-11 | 17 |
| B | 2023-01-11 | 23 |
| A | 2023-01-13 | 18 |
| B | 2023-01-13 | 24 |
| B | 2023-01-17 | 26 |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 32 |

Think about this as measured values for entities (A,B,C...) that appear with a date as timestamp. So for instance A has a value of 17 at 2023-01-11 and a new value of 18 at 2023-01-13.

What I need to identify is, at a given date, what is the "latest value" for each Id. So given a date of 2023-01-14, I would expect

| Id | Updated | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-13 | 18 |
| B | 2023-01-13 | 24 |

so ignore the value for "c" as it has not appeared yet, and the most recent values for A and B are used

whereas with a date of 2023-01-18 we get

| Id | Updated | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-13 | 18 |
| B | 2023-01-17 | 26 |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 32 |

The SQL to perform this would be

```sql
SELECT * FROM Readings r
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM Readings r2
  WHERE r.Id = r2.Id
  AND r2.Updated <= 2023-01-18 -- our search date here
  HAVING r.Updated = MAX(r2.Updated)
)
```

So the EXISTS pre-selects those rows where we have readings before the desired date and the HAVING ensures that the outer query's results are limited to those that match the MAX value of the Updated field.

This works - but I an just unable to figure out how this translates to EF core 6.

I have tried a number of variations. As far as I understand it, the EXISTS translates to a .Any(), something along the lines of

```csharp
var query = _context.Readings
.Where(r => r.Any(r2 => r.Id = r2.Id && r2.Updated <= fromDate);
```

But this will only filter out those that are time-wise after the search-date, I still need to couple it to the Max value of the available Update values, in order to only get the "latest" reading for each Id.

Particularly, all examples of "HAVING" seem to do a .GropuBy() follow by a .Where(), which I can't get to do what I need.

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by @PanagiotisKanavos the following does the trick:

```csharp
var history=context.Readings
   .GroupBy(r=>r.Id)                                      
   .Select(g=>
      g.OrderByDescending(r=>(DateTime?)r.Updated)
      .FirstOrDefault()
   ).ToList();
```

which translates into (generated columns names replaced with *, 2023-02-02 used as test search date)

```sql
SELECT [t0].*
FROM (
    SELECT [n].[Id]
    FROM [Readings] AS [n]
    WHERE [n].[Updated] <= '2023-02-02'
    GROUP BY [n].[Id]
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t1].*
    FROM (
        SELECT [n0].*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [n0].[Id] ORDER BY [n0].[Updated] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [Readings] AS [n0]
        WHERE [n0].[Updated] <= '2023-02-02'
    ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[Id]
```

Due to the nature of data we have to be able to update data for any date at any given time, so we might get a new value for C, valid for 2023-01-17 two days later, at which time we will overwrite

| Id | Updated | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 32 |

with

| Id | Updated | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 34 |

Since this happens days later, we cannot use the temporal tables feature of MSSQL to do an AS OF query, since the AS OF will look a the ValidFrom and ValidTo columns, which will (for the example given) be valid from 2023-01-19 hh:mm:ss. Hence, the temporal table in our case contains the "old" and overwritten value for C at 2023-01-17, so kind of an audit trail table registrering all changes, whereas the main table contain all relevant data.
We're not only trying to fetch the most recent dataset from the main table, but also need to support sort-of-going-back-in-time, but ignoring the overwritten values which live in the history-table. A more complete picture would be like this:

Main table:

| Id | Updated | Value | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-11 | 17 | 2023-01-11 05:13:59.3644385 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| B | 2023-01-11 | 23 | 2023-01-11 05:13:59.3644495 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| A | 2023-01-13 | 18 | 2023-01-13 05:13:47.1873642 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| B | 2023-01-13 | 24 | 2023-01-13 05:13:47.1873754 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| B | 2023-01-17 | 26 | 2023-01-17 05:13:23.6528734 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 34 | 2023-01-19 16:45:43.2543217 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |

History table:

| Id | Updated | Value | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2023-01-17 | 32 | 2023-01-17 05:13:23.6528866 | 2023-01-19 16:45:43.2543217 |

Notice how only the single overwritten value for C appears in the history table, and no query would need to retrieve this value, but we keep it for audit purposes.

So to sum up, the solution by @PanagiotisKanavos works, but does not end up as the desired SQL with a "HAVING"-clause, but maybe that just isn't possible with EF Core 6.

Other solutions that illustrate how EF Core 6 lamda expressions translate into a HAVING solving the same problem would be very welcome, for now I will mark @PanagiotisKanavos answer as the solution - I hope I can update it later if a better solution is submitted.

**Edit 2:**

The generated SQL takes around 15 seconds on a 65k row dataset which I find unusually slow. Yet, there are 235 columns, so a lot of data for each row. But it might also be due to a slow server.
Running the generated SQL's top part (with the group by)

```sql
    SELECT [n].[Id]
    FROM [Readings] AS [n]
    WHERE [n].[Updated] <= '2023-02-02'
    GROUP BY [n].[Id]
```

takes no time, whereas the SELECT inside the LEFT JOIN

```sql
    SELECT [t1].*
    FROM (
        SELECT [n0].*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [n0].[Id] ORDER BY [n0].[Updated] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [Readings] AS [n0]
        WHERE [n0].[Updated] <= '2023-02-02'
    ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
```

takes all the time.

The table has a single clustered key/index:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Readings] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Readings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Updated] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Could this be optimized?

Comment: That's not how you'd do it in SQL to begin with. The PK is supposed to uniquely identify a row. It looks like you used a single table for current and historical values and now look for  a way to get the current values. The easy solution is to just not mix current and historical values. Use a separate `...History` table. All SQL Server versions in mainstream support have temporal tables, which take care of this automatically. If you have to, user `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of the very expensive `GROUP BY` to identify the latest row in a result set.

Comment: If IDENTITY, please use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a comment it looks like the *real* problem is how to handle valid time, not get the latest row per ID. The [Temporal Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) page explains that a temporal table can have different times :

> - Valid time is the time period during or event time at which a fact is true in the real world.
> - Transaction time is the time at which a fact was recorded in the database.

Transaction time is referred as SYSTEM TIME in SQL Server and other databases. SQL Server doesn't have valid time.

I assume that `Readings` in this case is a table with sensor readings that are Valid for a specific period (Valid Time) but are recorded at different times (System Time).

Valid time can be supported by adding `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` columns to the table. It can't be handled with an `Updated` column. This is how both system and valid time were handled before SQL Server added explicit support for SYSTEM TIME. Either triggers or stored procedures can be used to ensure the fields are valid, and that editing the row generates the correct historical rows.

Assuming the fields are correct and covered by indexes, searching for readings for a specific date can be as easy as :

```
WHERE @date BETWEEN ValidFrom and ValidTo`
```

That translates easily to LINQ:

```
.Where(r=> r.ValidFrom >= thatDate && thatDate <= r.ValidTo)
```

It can even be combined with System time to check what readings were recorded from a specific sensor at a specific time. It's quite possible that the readings were corrected, eg due to an error or because we reloaded the CSV that contained them.

In that case

```
.TemporalAsOf(timeStamp2)
.Where(r=> r.ValidFrom >= thatDate && thatDate <= r.ValidTo)
```

Will use both valid and system time.

---

First of all, that's not how you'd do it in SQL. You use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) where available, separate history tables if not, and if neither is available, [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to number the rows in a result set. Mixing current and historical values in the same table causes performance problems to begin with.

**SQL - Temporal tables**

If you use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server you can use `AS OF somedate` to retrieve the state of the table at that date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Readings FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @someDate
```

**SQL - Latest row in set**

If you can't use proper history tables, the following query will number rows per ID by update time and only return the latest, in a single scan.  :

```
with x as (
    SELECT * ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Updated desc) AS RN
    FROM Readings r
)
SELECT *
FROM x
where RN=1
```

**EF Core 6+ - Temporal Tables**

Support for Temporal Tables was added [in EF Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#sql-server-temporal-tables). A normal LINQ query will return the currently valid rows. To get data in the past, [TemporalAsOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-cyrl-rs/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbsetextensions.temporalasof?view=efcore-6.0) is used to generate the `SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` clause :

```
var history = context
    .Readings
    .TemporalAsOf(timeStamp2)
    .Where(...);
```

**EF Core - ROW_Number with FromSql**
There's no direct support for `ROW_NUMBER()` yet. One way to use it would be to use `FromSql/FromSqlInterpolated` to generate it, then add extra filters to the query. For this to work though, the entity type would need to have a row number property :

```
var history=context.Recordings.FromSql($@"SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Updated desc) RN
    FROM Readings r")
                   .Where(r=>r.RN==1)
                   .ToList();
```

**EF Core 6+ - First row per group**

EF Core 6 also added the ability to [return the first N items per group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#improved-groupby-support), which can be used in this case to return the first item per ID:

```
var history=context.Readings
                   .GroupBy(r=>r.Id)
                   .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(r=>r.Updated).FirstOrDefault())
                   .ToList();
```

The final query will include a `GROUP BY` so I doubt it will be as lightweight as using `ROW_NUMBER()` directly. One would have to compare the actual execution plans to see whether SQL Server can simplify it and how expensive it will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very thorough answer. We do actually utilize temporal tables, but the problem is that new values or updates to existing may come in at a different date, so the ValidFrom and ValidTo datetime2 fields do not reflect the "correct" value, e.g. may be 2 days later.  Hence, I cant see that the "as of" will work, since Updated may equal 2023-01-17, but ValidFrom may be 2023-01-19 16:45:12. Don't you agree? I'll update the question with details regarding "EF Core 6+ - First row per group" which works - albeit slow since is a 65000+ row dataset. Thanks again!

Comment: `We do actually utilize temporal tables` that's a significant detail that should be in the question itself. `GROUP BY` is a bad idea in every case though. Update the question and explain what's actually going on. 65K is no data at all and shouldn't take any time. It can easily fit in the CPU's cache. Why aren't you using `ROW_NUMBER()`? While `.GroupBy(r=>r.Id).Select(...)` works, it *will* group the entire table unless you add filtering before it. Have you tried executing the SQL clause using `ROW_NUMBER()` directly? How does it compare to the `GroupBy` clause?

Comment: As for the temporal table, what you talk is application/valid time, not transaction/system time. It's treated the same way system/transaction time is - with separate, indexed `From` and `To` tables that specify the row's validity. This way, searching for eg rules that are valid for a specific period means searching for rows whose valid times cover a specific date. Tables that have both valid and transaction time are called bitemporal tables. SQL Server doesn't support bitemporal tables or valid time

Comment: @JanHansen I modified the answer to explain about Valid time. You need two fields for this to work, same as for System time. You'll have to write application code or use stored procedures to ensure the ValidFrom and ValidTo fields are always correct. A trigger can't guess whether an update refers to valid time or not

Comment: thanks again! As I understand your answer, SQL server supports only Transaction time, not Valid time, in its temporal table implementation, which is why I can't "just" do the AS OF search, but will need to implement my own from/to fields if I want a better solution. However, while data originates from CSV it's fed into the main table through another system, so an application solution or trigger that updates the "previous" row for A with a suitable ValidTo value when something new arrives would then be needed. I'll look into that.

Comment: The readings are not valid for a specific period of time, but rater "until a newer value appears". Which may be never, or every day. I have updated the question with timing running the SQL from SSMS and the index of the table.